# Error in SQL Server CTE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I believe I'm writing this CTE wrong, I'm a major novice with this so explain as much as you can. Still getting the can not be bound error on almost everything

Error messages:

> The multi part identifier could not be bound "PS_Margin.Emp or Vendor ID
>
> The multi part identifier could not be bound "PS_Margin.Project Profit by Person %

Issues/ Goals:

Possible need to add aliases to column names with spaces and special characters although I don't know how to do this

```
WITH

Profit_Score_CTE ( [Emp or Vendor ID], [Project Profit by Person %] ) AS (
    SELECT PS_Margin.[Emp or Vendor ID], 
        CASE
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .4 THEN 1
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .2 THEN 3
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .1 THEN 5
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .05 THEN 8
        ELSE 13 END
        AS [Profit Score]
    FROM dbo.PS_Margin AS ps
)

 SELECT emp.[Employee Name], emp.[USID], [Profit Score]*0.3  AS [Final Score]
 FROM   dbo.PS_Emp AS emp
    left join Profit_Score_CTE 
    ON emp.USID = Profit_Score_CTE.[Emp or Vendor ID]
```

Comment: Does the field 'Project Profit by Person %' exist in PS_Margin?

Comment: Show us the DDL for `PS_Margin`.

Comment: I would use reasonable names for columns. Using things like spaces and special characters makes it far more difficult to query. If you want spaces displayed in the front end then it should be handled in the front end.

Comment: Project Profit by Person % does exists in the table

Comment: @TAD You are not really helping anyone understand your issues. You have edited your question and completely removed the error message. You have added the complete query (good) but it is now difficult to understand your problems and goals. Does the query still produce an error? Incorrect data?

Comment: And your second CTE is incorrect because it is attempting to define the name of the cte as Long_Score_CTE while also selecting from a table of that name. It also refers to columns using the alias PS_Long which is not mentioned at all in the from clause. Divide and conquer is my suggestion - you can't write this big complicated query in one go. So start small. Take the first cte and verify that it works as a single select statement. Repeat as needed. Once everything works correctly you can then combine them into a single statement.

Comment: Still getting the bound error PS_Margin.[Emp or Vendor ID] and PS_Margin.[Project Profit by Person %]. Basically getting the bound error on all objects. The first commenter mentioned it might be alias', how do I add them at this point and then reference them again?

Comment: @SMor - I'll work on making this smaller. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Appreciate all the suggestions BTW. Thanks for helping a super novice

Comment: What are the actual table definitions from which you are querying the data? It looks like one table object may be PS_Margin? What's the table definition? While your style of CTE syntax technically works, it's more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: dbo.PS_Margin - how do I make it simpler?

Comment: Is `[Project Profit by Person %]` real table name?

Comment: @JohnyL The table name is PS_Margin. Let me know if I'm not answering your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot be bound" usually refers to how you are ID'ing columns with a table alias. Try giving your table an alias and using that for the columns:

```
    WITH
--Section 1: Profit Score   
Profit_Score_CTE( [Emp or Vendor ID], [Project Profit by Person %] ) AS (
    SELECT PS_Margin.[Emp or Vendor ID], 
    CASE
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .4 THEN 1
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .2 THEN 3
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .1 THEN 5
        WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .05 THEN 8
        ELSE 13 END
        AS [Profit Score]
    FROM [dbo].[PS_Margin] ps
)
```

Comment: HOw do I give it an alias? I'm a super novice... so just figuring this out

Comment: wait you did that up there... apologies, let me try this out

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because you haven't provided enough information to reproduce the error.  But I think the problem might be that you define the columns of your CTE here:

```
Profit_Score_CTE( [Emp or Vendor ID], [Project Profit by Person %] ) AS (
```

And yet you alias your second column with a different name here:

```
AS [Profit Score]
```

You need to decide which column name you want your CTE to expose and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your CTE is correctly defined. Your cte is named "Profit_Score_CTE". Your actual select statement refers to objects dbo.PS_Emp and dbo.PS. I'll guess that you should replace dbo.PS with your CTE name. E.g.,

```
with Profit_Score_CTE as (select ...) 
select emp.[Employee Name], ...
from dbo.PS_Emp as emp
left join Profit_Score_CTE
   on emp.USID = Profit_Score_CTE.[Emp or Vendor ID]
order by ...
;
```

The alias PS is visible only inside the definition of the CTE. It cannot be used in the actual select statement that uses your CTE. Notice that I gave your table an alias and used it - a consistent coding style is something you should strive to achieve. Also notice the order by clause. Rows within a resultset have no defined order without one - and usually it is important. And PLEASE use white space to make your code readable and to avoid easy mistakes. You crammed everything together in the formula for computed column [Final Score].

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect these changes. Same errors but l believe I'm getting closer. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help!

My newbie ribbon was really showing with this one. The problem had nothing to do with SQL at all. I wasn't pointing to the correct database in sql server.

In the available databases drop down box on the top left hand screen of SQL Server you need to select the database you're working from. This will enable the script to find your database, and begin to solve alot of the errors.