# Error in CTE: The multi part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Structure:

```
dbo.PS_Margin
```

2 Columns

```
[Project Profit by Person %], [Emp or Vendor ID]
```

Error Messages:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.PS_Margin'
>
> (Solved) The multi part identifier could not be bound "PS_Margin.Emp or Vendor ID

Issues/ Goals:

1. Error messages above
2. Possible need to add aliases (or fix current aliases) to column names with spaces and special characters although I don't know how to do this

   ```
   WITH Profit_Score_CTE ( [Emp or Vendor ID], [Project Profit by Person %], [Profit Score] ) AS (
   SELECT ps.[Emp or Vendor ID], [Profit Score], 
       CASE
       WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .4 THEN 1
       WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .2 THEN 3
       WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .1 THEN 5
       WHEN ps.[Project Profit by Person %] > .05 THEN 8
       ELSE 13 END
       AS [Profit Score]
   FROM dbo.PS_Margin ps )

   SELECT PS_Emp.[Employee Name], PS_Emp.[USID], [Profit Score]*0.3  AS [Final Score]
     FROM dbo.PS_Emp LEFT OUTER JOIN Profit_Score_CTE ps
      ON PS_Emp.[USID] = ps.[Emp or Vendor ID]
   ```

Comment: You have defined the CTE but you are not using it.

Comment: Add table structure for us simulate the query

Comment: I just added the table structure at the top, just two columns.

Comment: Is this the exact same question from you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968005/error-in-sql-cte-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT PS_Emp.[Employee Name], PS_Emp.[USID], [Profit Score]*0.3  AS [Final Score]
FROM dbo.PS_Emp LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Profit_Score_CTE ps
     ON PS_Emp.[USID] = ps.[Emp or Vendor ID]
```

You have defined the CTE but you are not using it.

Comment: This worked for the above error - woot! Now I'm getting the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.PS_Margin'